# rubymine でプロジェクトバーなどにフォーカスがあるときに、エディタにフォーカスを戻すには？

Tags: rubymine

rubymine でプロジェクトバーなどにフォーカスがあるときに、エディタにフォーカスを戻すには、どのコマンドを使えば良いですか？

現在はトラックパッドでクリックしています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

⌘↓(Jump to Source)はいかがでしょう?